# How to exit "While True" with enter key | Throws Value Error can't convert str to float

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, exit

I have converted the base program into two functions. I need to be able to exit the program by hitting the enter/return key but when I do, it throws a ValueError: could not covert string to float.

I have tried assigning the var(x) outside of the loop and also tried using an if statement to close but the issue seems to be with the float attached to the input. I'm wondering if I can move the float statement to another part of the program and still get the correct output?

import math
def newton(x):
    tolerance = 0.000001
    estimate = 1.0
    while True:
        estimate = (estimate + x / estimate) / 2
        difference = abs(x - estimate ** 2)
        if difference <= tolerance:
            break
        return estimate

def main():

```
while True:
    x = float(input("Enter a positive number or enter/return to quit: "))
    print("The program's estimate is", newton(x))
    print("Python's estimate is     ", math.sqrt(x))
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()

My expectation is that when the user hits the enter key, the program will end with no errors. The float is needed for the program.

File "C:/Users/travisja/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 13, in main
    x = float(input("Enter a positive number or enter/return to quit: "))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because it's trying to convert the input received when hitting just `Enter` (an empty string) to a `float`. An empty string can't be converted to a float, thus the error.

You can re-structure your code easily, though:

```py
import math

# Prompt the user for a number first time
input_val = input("Enter a positive number or enter/return to quit: ")

# Continue until user hits Enter
while input_val:
    try:
        x = float(input_val)
        print("The program's estimate is", newton(x))
        print("Python's estimate is     ", math.sqrt(x))

    # Catch if we try to calculate newton or sqrt on a negative number or string
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Input {input_val} is not a valid number")

    finally:
        input_val = input("Enter a positive number or enter/return to quit: ")
```

Comment: This helped. I needed to drop the "finally:" and move the second "input" to the "try" and it is now doing what I expected. Thank you. I've never used those before. Very helpful.